# Word like "decadence" for declining skill

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to fill in the gap in a sentence like this:

> John's true skills were stagnating, even regressing, and in his ___, he increasingly indulged in fanciful daydreams where he would save the day, instead of facing his difficulties head-on.

I'm thinking  of the word "decadence", but I feel like there's a word I'm not remembering that's a better fit.

Comment: I think a bit more context is necessary. What sort of decadence - material, moral? Why is this guy dreaming of saving the day? What were his true skills?

Comment: This is purely material - he just is losing his touch at his profession, and he's avoiding dealing with it or trying to correct it by retreating into fantasy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Decline* was the first word that came to me, too.

If you're looking for a word to describe his funk itself, though, what about something like *indifference* or *lassitude*? Even *malaise* might fit.

These aren't synonyms of decadence, of course, but when I read your sentence, decadence isn't the word that jumps out at me.

Comment: No problem. I think @kylben's *downward spiral* would do well, too.

Answer (score 2):

As alternatives, my ‘Collins Thesaurus’ gives *degeneration, decline, corruption, fall, decay, deterioration, dissolution, perversion, dissipation, debasement* and *retrogression*. But then again, perhaps you don’t mean *decadence* at all.

Comment: *perversion* and *debasement* have a moral connotation that I'm not looking for - *deterioration* and *decay* are along the right lines. I suppose I might say John is just "in a funk", but I'm looking a word to describe being in that state.

Answer (score 2):

The word I'd put into that sentence is "decline".  "Downward spiral" could work, or if you want to express more of a mood, "funk" or "rut" might work. "Decay" hints at "decadence" without the moralistic overtones.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to attribute John's decline in skills to age, you might use words like [dotage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dotage), [senescence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/senescence), and [wane](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wane) or [waning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waning) years.

Comment: Was going to suggest **dotage**. Best fit for that place in the sentence anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about "and as his X dulled", where X is a a [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) for activity John had been skilled in?

Answer (score 0):

"Atrophy" has a specific meaning in a medical context, but it could be used creatively in your context to suggest a loss of his former strength.